# Can I get a 301 redirect to show info from the destination page?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am using the 301 Redirect rule in my .htaccess file to send from my server to a completely different web server.

My domain is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

```
Redirect 301 /me http://www.facebook/username
```

The redirect work works fine, but if I were to post this on Facebook, or say another webpage, the header and title info that shows up on Facebok.com is:

EXAMPLE.COM
**[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)**

Is there a way for the redirect to point to the new page's title. keywords and info?

Comment: If you redirect elsewhere, then Facebook will try and fetch OG meta data from the new URL.

Comment: Sadly it appears not to

Comment: There is detail lacking here, to be able to say what is actually going on. According to the code example, you are redirecting to a Facebook user profile (for whatever reason), the screenshot then shows warptv.com, but it doesn’t look like that is where the redirect is implemented either.

Comment: @CBroe The example I put up was misleading. My simple question is this: a 301 redirect works. However, if you're posting on social media, say Facebook, Facebook will not grab the meta data from the redirected link, but from where the 301 redirect lies. Can this be changed?

Comment: Only if you don’t redirect the Facebook scraper. It can be recognized by its user agent.